# Select Anchor tag using JavaScript which is dynamically rendered in the DOM using PHP & Fetch API

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, fetch-api

I'm trying to get the element (anchor tag using class name) using JavaScript which is rendered in the DOM dynamically using PHP and Fetch API. But I'm not able to do this. I've tried many methods but unfortunately not working any methods. But when I do same in jQuery then I can easily get the element by using this...

```
$(document).on('click', '.delBtn', function(){

});
```

But the same thing I want to do with JavaScript.

This is my index.php coding

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header lead">All Users</div>
      <div class="card-body pre-scrollable" style="max-height: 352px !important;">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="showUsers">

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my script.js coding

```
  const showUsers = document.getElementById('showUsers');
  async function readData() {
    const response = await fetch('action.php?read=1', {
      method: 'GET'
    });
    const data = await response.text();
    showUsers.innerHTML = data;
  }
  readData();
```

And this is my php coding from where I'm sending the html data

```
if (isset($_GET['read'])) {
    $data = $user->read();
    $output = '';
    if ($data) {
      foreach ($data as $row) {
        $output .= '<tr>
                      <td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>
                      <td>' . $row['first_name'] . '</td>
                      <td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>
                      <td>' . $row['phone'] . '</td>
                      <td>
                        <a href="#" id="' . $row['id'] . '" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill editLink">Edit</a>
                        
                        <a href="#" id="' . $row['id'] . '" class="badge badge-danger badge-pill deleteLink">Del</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>';
      }
      echo $output;
    }
  }
```

Now I want the value of id attribute when I click on delete anchor tag using JavaScript.

Comment: What `.delBtn` are you referring to? Did you mean the `.deleteLink`? If so, you can just access the id using `this.id` inside the event handler.

Comment: I've just written a sample jQuery script there......I want to do the same with vanilla JavaScript

Comment: Then please show us the vanilla dom javascript that you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach the event via `addEventListener` via its anchor class and get the `id` attribute

```js
const elems = document.getElementsByClassName('delBtn');

for(let ele of elems) {
  ele.addEventListener('click', onDeleteCliked);
}


function onDeleteCliked(event) {
  console.log('id', event.target.id);
}
```

```html
<button class="delBtn" id="1">Delete Button</button>
```

While adding dynamic event handlers, you just need to add the following line of code as well

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   if(e.target && e.target.classList.value.indexOf('delBtn') !== -1) {
     ele.addEventListener('click', onDeleteCliked);
  }
});
```

Comment: I know this using jQuery but I want to know how to do the same using vanilla JavaScript

Comment: will this work on dynamically added html data on the DOM as you can see in my question???

Comment: Because I can't find the html coding in view source which is rendered dynamically

Comment: @DCodeMania see the update answer, it should work with dynamic elements as well

Comment: Instead of `.getAttribute('id')` just write `.id`

Comment: Yes working but this I've to change something in your code....by the thanks for the help.....!!!

Comment: @DCodeMania you can accept the answer oif it's working for you

Comment: I've added an answer below that code is working fine!!!

Comment: @DCodeMania we invest our time to answer question and you would post your own by copying and pasting the same answer by just changing the class.

Comment: In your code you have just used click event then inside this there is another same event thats why your code was not working......class name is not matter here.....!!!!